# How to get unique values from a pair of columns in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

I have a table in Google Sheets with a structure similar to this:

| Player | Hometown | Points |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Amy | Mapleton | 25 |
| Amy | Mapleton | 50 |
| Amy | Mapleton | 150 |
| Bret | Jersey | 10 |
| Colin | Hocksfield | 5 |
| Colin | Hocksfield | 15 |
| David | Mapleton | 200 |
| Ella | Benning | 70 |
| Fred | Hocksfield | 20 |
| George | Jersey | 50 |
| Harold | Dover | 30 |

Except there's about 330 unique hometown values.

I'm trying to get a count of the hometowns that have the most number of players, which would look something like this based on the data above:

| Hometown | Players |
| --- | --- |
| Mapleton | 2 |
| Hocksfield | 2 |
| Jersey | 2 |
| Benning | 1 |
| Dover | 1 |

(There are only 2 players from Mapleton, even though there are 4 "point records" for Mapleton.)

Can somebody help me with a query that would return how many players there are in each hometown, that I can use in a Google Sheet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `QUERY()` function like-

```
=QUERY(UNIQUE(A2:B),
"select Col2, count(Col1) 
where Col2 is not null
group by Col2 
order by count(Col1) DESC 
label Col2 'Hometown', count(Col1) 'Playes'")
```

[image]

Comment: This was super helpful and did the job perfectly, thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 1):

**Use this**

```
=ArrayFormula({
 $B$1,$A$1; UNIQUE(B2:B), IF(UNIQUE(B2:B)="",,
 COUNTIF(QUERY(UNIQUE($A$2:$B)," Select Col2"),"="&UNIQUE(B2:B)))})
```

[image]